# String column to date column

Tags: sql, date, error-handling, google-bigquery, casting

I am trying to convert a string column to a date column.  The string column is saved as 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

The data looks like this:

| USER_ID | STATUS_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 01/01/2001 |
| 102 | 20/04/2001 |

```
   SELECT
      USER_ID,
      CAST(STATUS_DATE AS DATE) AS STATUS_DATE
   FROM DATASET
```

However, I get the error message of "Invalid date: '20/04/2001'" when I run it.

How do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Use a format clause, as defined in the documentation

Comment: `PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', STATUS_DATE)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date).

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', STATUS_DATE) AS STATUS_DATE
FROM DATASET
```